# Ubuntu 16.04 Latest Update Broke Graphics

Tags: 16.04, drivers, radeon, amd-graphics

I updated my Ubuntu 16.04 to the latest one. It looks like the Radeon open source is not working even though it's installed. The graphics is stretched horizontally. This command:

```
lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
```

outputs the following:

```
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] BeaverCreek [Radeon HD 6520G]
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd BeaverCreek [Radeon HD 6520G]
    Kernel modules: radeon
--
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Seymour [Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series]
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Radeon HD 7470M
    Kernel modules: radeon
```

I tried to install the amdgpu-pro from AMD site but Ubuntu is stuck (loop) in login.

I can't seem to make it work after trying workaround from other questions already answered.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several updates (maybe 4-6 times) and after removing old kernels, graphics got fixed. It has even become better.